# Trouble understanding solution to old GoogleCodeJam

Tags: python

[Here](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p0) is the link to the Google Code Jam problem from 2010.

```
from sys import *

def solve(_, items,p):
    for i in xrange(len(items)):
        for j in xrange(i+1,len(items)):
            if items[i] + items[j] == c:
                print "Case #%d: %d %d" %(_+1,i+1,j+1)

cases = int(raw_input())
for _ in xrange(cases):
    c = int(raw_input())
    i = int(raw_input())
    items = map(int,stdin.readline().split())
    solve(_,items,c)
```

After attempting to trying to work the problem on my own, and afterward referring to this code that I found on Google's solution site, there is one part of it that I cannot seem to figure out. That is on line 12:

```
i = int(raw_input())
```

I don't see how it is being used at all in the code besides this initial declaration. Yet if I comment the line out the code will not run, giving the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5 75 25'
```

Could someone explain why this line is needed and how it is being used in the code?

Comment: maybe better suited to stackexchange.com/codereview?

Comment: raw_input consumes input from stdin. They probably dont need i to solve the problem, but if they don't consume it, the next time they get c, they will really be consuming i instead ( ie all of their input processing will get off count ).

Comment: @KevinDTimm No, Code Review certainly isn't for “help me understand this code I found” kind of questions.

Comment: @bwbrowning I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty directly following the instructions in the problem:

> The first line of input gives the number of cases, N. N test cases follow.

```
cases = int(raw_input())
```

> For each test case there will be:

```
for _ in xrange(cases):
```

> One line containing the value C, the amount of credit you have at the store.

```
    c = int(raw_input())
```

> One line containing the value I, the number of items in the store.

```
    i = int(raw_input())
```

> One line containing a space separated list of I integers.

```
    items = map(int,stdin.readline().split())
```

Your confusion, I think, stems from commenting out the line where `i` is defined without understanding the side-effects of setting `i`.  The python code doesn't need to do anything with `i` because `split()` works without needing to know how many items there are (some languages might need this information, so the problem provides it), however we still need to call `raw_input()` in order to advance past that line and read the list of items.

You could therefore remove the `i = int(...)` and just call `raw_input()` on that line and the code would still work.  The author was simply following the documented steps of processing the input, even if `solve()` doesn't need it.